# Different roles for methods in a class

Tags: c#, authorization

I am modifying an existing class so that one method will allow a different role and  I do not want any of the other methods to have that role.

```
[Authorize("addedit, admin")]
public class JobsController : BaseODataController<Job>
{
    //This method needs to allow one more role!
    public Job Get(int Id)
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(Job job)
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is by adding this role I need to add it at the class level and that would give this role access to all the methods of this class. I want this role to access the class but then ONLY be able to use this one method. The simplest way to make this work is to remove the attributes at the class level and then have -

```
[Authorize("addedit, admin, newrole")]
public Job Get(int Id)
{
    //stuff
}

[Authorize("addedit, admin")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Job job)
{
    //stuff
}
```

However in reality this class actually has many different methods, so doing this for each one is messy. Without doing this or splitting this method into it's own class is there any way to allow access to this class and only one method via a new role?

Comment: What happens if you leave `[Authorize("addedit, admin")]` at the Controller level and add `[Authorize("addedit, admin, newrole")]` at the specific Action?

Comment: This doesn't work because the user only has the "newrole" so they don't get beyond the authorization at the class level.

Comment: If there's so many methods in 1 controller why not split the controller? with using [Route] you can still map the other mappoints to the same endpoint but you can create a controller for each usergroup. Maybe you can even make the controller static?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no way to perform it with default `Authorize` attribute. In short, you are looking for something like that;

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "addedit, admin", Except = "Get")]
public class JobsController : BaseODataController<Job>
{
    [MyAuthorize(Roles = "addedit, admin, newrole")]
    public Job Get(int Id)
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(Job job)
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

You should provide your **custom derived Authorize** attribute for it.

if you want to check roles manually in action, another option is `[AllowAnonymous]`. Something like;

```
[Authorize("addedit, admin")]
public class JobsController : BaseODataController<Job>
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public Job Get(int Id)
    {
        //Check the roles (addedit, admin, newrole) manually

        //stuff
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(Job job)
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```